# How can I define a SQL-query whitelist for a database user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I want limit the database access for a client. How can I define a explicit white list of SQL queries, witch can only execute a database user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do the following:

1. Remove read access from all tables for the user.
2. Define views for each of the allowed queries.
3. Be sure that the security for the views is declared as `DEFINER` rather than `INVOKER`.

Voila!  The user has access to the views, but not to the underlying tables.

Comment: It's a right solution. This only control the data view and not the art of access. But I try now to go over a stored procedure. There I can check SQL explicit. On using only views it's possible to SQL injection, i.e. for init long running queries.

Comment: @Gerd . . . If you have no control over security access, well, then you can't control security access.  You need the cooperation of the DBA to do what you want.

Comment: I'm the DBA. Your solution is OK on the viewpoint of restrict the dataset. But if a user have a access over views, he has a free choice of access path in the view and so he can take a bad and make bad load on DB server.  I think it's possible to improve your solution with a stored procedure.